# Author Meta in Author URL Link

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks, links

I am trying to modify the default author link url structure. In the URL, I would also like to change the string **author** to **operator** add some author meta along with the username.

So far, I have successfully changed the string **author** to **operator** but I would also like to add the country (author meta) he/she belongs in the url. So the modified url should be like this: ***example.com/country-name/operator/newuser***

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example / idea and I haven't tested if this really works. But I think it could be something along these lines.

```
function custom_author_base() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    global $wp_query;
    // On author pages you get current author for example with $wp_query
    $curauth = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    // Get the required data
    $country = get_user_meta($curauth->ID, 'country_meta_key', true);
    // Turn the country into url friendly format and prepend it to operator
    $author_slug = sanitize_title($country) . '/operator';
    // Set the custom string as author base
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = $author_slug;
}
add_action('init', 'custom_author_base');
```

This example will propably need some tweaking. You might also need extra functions to handle other cases than the auhtor page where the author page url is shown. E.g. `get_author_posts_url` might need some tweaking I guess.

I hope this helps you achieve the result you're looking for. Or perhaps others can build on this and help you find a more complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help but as the `global $wp_query;` is not available yet because the function is hooked on `init`. So, it can't be achieved that way.

Comment: Ah, indeed. I'll think of another possible solution.